# Why is the query result in php different from what I try in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [SubID] => 19 [0] => 19 [RandomCode] =>
>   P57bz0y24DdKofbI6M4BqJfDs0QNtL2XpBANnzys [1] =>
>   P57bz0y24DdKofbI6M4BqJfDs0QNtL2XpBANnzys [Email] => as@sasa.com [2] =>
>   as@sasa.com [CreateDate] => 2012-03-25 [3] => 2012-03-25 [UpdateDate]
>   => 0000-00-00 [4] => 0000-00-00 [27_t1] => [5] => [31_asas] => 0 [6] => 0 ) )

The result is like this now but i can not get it by

```
echo $result['Email'];
```

Why is the error? Thank you

Comment: Are you sure `$set['Attribute']`= 'Email' and `$sub`= '19' ?

Comment: sure , i have tried using a actual string instead of variable to test

Comment: with `array('`Email`', '19')` ?

Comment: $stmt->execute(array('Email','19'));

Comment: As you can see, there is not only one array, so logically you can't get the key Email because the outer array doesn't have that key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT   ?
```

not good!

the list of columns you're selecting shouldn't be a bind variable, because (as a string value) it will then be enclosed in quotes rather than backticks. MySQL will then treat it as a simple quoted string, and return that quoted string ('Email') rather than the actual column you want for each record that it returns.

Don't bind the column name. Use SELECT *, just the one bind variable for the SubID value in your WHERE clause.

When you've done fetchAll(), then walk the result extracting the column that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your result shows [Email] => Email which means, MySQL receives `SELECT 'Email' from subscriber WHERE SubID='19'`

He selects "Email" :) not the field named Email

Comment: sorry you mean to change $stmt->execute(array($set['Attribute'],$sub));?

Answer (score 0):

? changes to `'Email'` (not backticks). So do:

```
$sql = '
   SELECT   ' . $set['Attribute'] . '
   FROM     subscriber
   WHERE    SubID=?
';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($sub));
```

Comment: SELECT   ".$set['Attribute'].' result in  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\list\editSub.php on line 188

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [Email] => as@sasa.com [0] => as@sasa.com ) )

Comment: but why i can not get it by $row['Email']

Comment: An SQL query could give more than one row, though here it is at most one row. Hence: `$row[0]['Email']` or so.